# "As shown in from Table 1 to Table 5", is this correct? Or should I remove "from"?

Tags: grammar

I'm writing a research paper, and trying to show something in 5 tables. 
"As shown in from Table 1 to Table 5", is this correct? Or should I remove "from" or "in"?

It seems for referring to tables and figures in papers, usually they use the word "Table" and "Figure" with the first letter in capital. So usually they use "Figure 1" or "Fig. 1", depending on how the template defines the format of the titles of the figures. I just don't know how to deal with this when it comes to multiple tables/figures.

Comment: *As shown in Tables 1–5*, or *As shown in Tables 1 to 5*.

Comment: You need the *"in"*, and you can't use *"from"* and *"in"* at the same time. So *"As shown in Table 1 to Table 5"* is acceptable, but it's more concise to drop the second *"Table"* and pluralize the first.

Comment: If you're using "from ... to" in order to to emphasize the continuity of the tables you could phrase it as "As shown in Tables 1 *through* 5..."

Comment: You have a multitude of options. "In Tables 1 to 5", "in Tables 1 through 5", "in Tables 1–5", and even "in Table 1 to 5", "in Table 1 through 5", "in Table 1–5". What is *not* an option at *all*, that's "in from". To such an extent that I have to wonder why you are even considering it. Where have you even seen it, just once? It is entirely unheard of. Indeed, both BNC and COCA don't have a single hit. (And they do have thousands of hits for "as shown in", before you ask.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

> As shown in tables 1 to 5.

Answer (score 0):

"As shown in Tables 1 through 5" would be clearer.

(And having "from" in there is wrong.)